# Flyway false failure

Tags: mysql, jenkins, ansible, database-migration, flyway

We had a flyway migration come back as a failure in our jenkins job the other day. When we looked at the DB, we found the script was applied, but no entry was created in the "schema_version" table for the script. We know this script took a long time to apply (modifying a table with about 70M rows) and we used SQL syntax that would make the change non blocking at least (ALGORITHM=INPLACE on mysql). However when the script was finished, flyway returned with a failure to jenkins and did not run any scripts after this long one.

We are running flyway via the gradle plugin (version 3.2.1) and using ansible to call the gradle task. Jenkins calls ansible which calls gradle which calls flyway. Not sure if this is caused by flyway timing out or ansible maybe. We would like to not have this happen again in production though.

Our workaround was to manually put the entry into schema_version so that script would not get re-run, then re-apply the migration so the scripts after it would run.

We looked at the db and there was a coincidental connection spike around the same time, so maybe it ran into a connection limit, but I figured the connection would already be open if it was running the script.

The sanitized output from jenkins is as follows:

```
TASK: [flyway | run flywayMigrate] ******************************************** 
<db.server> REMOTE_MODULE command gradle -b /opt/product/rc/flyway-17.5.32.37534.d2bac4a/extracted/flyway.gradle flywayMigrate
failed: [db.server] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
invalid output was: SUDO-SUCCESS-plqsdlxwlfkdsujlxdafldpasvtllis
```

Comment: Is MySQL running with some kind of logging enabled? Most likely kind would be binlog for replication/incremental backup. If yes, check the MySQL logs, (e.g for binlog use `mysqlbinlog` utility to dump it), and try to get an idea of what MySQL was doing around that time. Note that binlog will only log updates that have actually modified something, so this will not give you the full picture, but may provide some clues.

Comment: thanks for the tip. Since this only happened on our production server, I don't actually have access to it (locked down for security). The script succeeded on our CERT environment that I have access to, so that's no good. I may be able to get someone to login to production but that is surprisingly challenging haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to the connection Flyway uses for the metadata table being closed by some part of your infrastructure (DB, proxy, ...), resulting in Flyway being unable to write the row to the table after the long-running migration completed.